# clueless to node variable passing

Tags: node.js, express

I've followed this tutorial http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/ customizing to fit my need of course. I'm now trying to implement a way to sort the userlist by clicking a font awesome icon. I know how to use 
`{$query: {}, $orderby: { "difficulty" : -1 }` in the find function to sort asc/desc but besides that I have no idea how to pass what ever I need as the "-1/1" depending on what icon is clicked.

Here is my relevant code in routes/index.js

```
/* GET Userlist page. */
router.get('/chorelist', function(req, res) {
     console.log(req)
     var db = req.db;
     var collection = db.get('chorecollection');
     collection.find({$query: {}, $orderby: { "difficulty" : -1 }},{},function(e,docs){
        res.render('chorelist', {
            "chorelist" : docs
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: read about query params http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.query

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it working with that. Finding what you need is tough without knowing what you're looking for.

Comment: as an add on, how would you recommend using queries like that. Should my icon just be a link to `localhost:3000/chorelist?order=desc` because that isn't working. only manually changing the url works

Comment: Fortunately this is one of the things that you only need to learn once. All other languages out there from Perl to Java to C++ call it "query parameters" as well.